# Remove the [Glitch] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

The [glitch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/glitch) tag has no use. The top five questions don't relate at all. In order:

- Glitch detection in MP3 files
- Glitchy GPU output
- Office 2013 drawing oddly
- Mouse moving on its own
- Sound card glitching

Comment: Do the authors mean "bug"?

Comment: Not necessarily.