# Glitch tag cleanup now completed

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

Similar to yesterday's question:  Looking at the planned [tag cleanup requests](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/status-planned), the tag [glitch](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/glitch) has now been cleared.  No questions remain.

So, can the question:  [Remove the [Glitch] tag](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9389/remove-the-glitch-tag)  now be set to status-completed?
It would help focus on those tags that still need to be cleaned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awesome. Well done! Tags updated :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it better to raise questions like this for completed tag cleanups, or simply flag->mod attention and explain that it's done? What do you guys prefer?

Comment: @Robotnik: Flag and/or `@ping` are fine